# Sampling Without Replacement Probabilities

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, permutation

I am using np.random.choice to do sampling without replacement.

I would like the following code to choose 0 50% of the time, 1 30% of the time, and 2 20% of the time.

```
import numpy as np

draws = []
for _ in range(10000):
    draw = np.random.choice(3, size=2, replace=False, p=[0.5, 0.3, 0.2])
    draws.append(draw)

result = np.r_[draws]
```

How can I correctly choose the parameters for `np.random.choice` to give me the result that I want?

The numbers I want represent the probability of the events being drawn in either 1st or 2nd position exclusively.

```
print(np.any(result==0, axis=1).mean()) # 0.83, want 0.8
print(np.any(result==1, axis=1).mean()) # 0.68, want 0.7
print(np.any(result==2, axis=1).mean()) # 0.47, want 0.5
```

Comment: See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.sample.html#numpy.random.sample

Comment: What you want seems ill specified. If you sample without replacement the draws are not independent. Yet you measure the final probability over all draws as if they were independent. (If you do `.mean(axis=0)` you will see that you get the expected result for the first draw only.) Are you absolutely totally entirely sure this is exactly what you want?

Comment: In order for `(result == 0).mean()` to equal `0.5` without replacement, it would have to be selected in *every trial* (in either the first or second selection).  Obviously this would not be likely.

Comment: To solve the problem as stated you can compute the final probabilities using [Wallenius' noncentral hypergoemetric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallenius%27_noncentral_hypergeometric_distribution#Multivariate_distribution) and solve for the initial weights. Personally, I think implementing that would lead down a particularly horrible rabbit hole...

Comment: that . . .isn't a typo.  It's a complete reformulation of the problem (which, granted, was necessary)

Comment: And this should probably be asked on [math.se] instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm giving two interpretations of the problem. One I prefer ("Timeless") and one I consider technically valid but inferior ("Naive")

## Timeless:

Given probabilities `x, y, z` this approach computes `x', y', z'` such that if we draw twice independently and discard all equal pairs the frequencies of `0, 1, 2` are `x, y, z`.

This gives the right total frequencies over both trials and has the added benefit of being simple and being timeless in the sense that first and second trial are equivalent.

For this to hold we must have

```
(x'y' + x'z') / [2 (x'y' + x'z' + y'z')] = x
(x'y' + y'z') / [2 (x'y' + x'z' + y'z')] = y                         (1)
(y'z' + x'z') / [2 (x'y' + x'z' + y'z')] = z
```

If we add two of those and subtract the third we get

```
x'y' / (x'y' + x'z' + y'z') =  x + y - z = 1 - 2 z
x'z' / (x'y' + x'z' + y'z') =  x - y + z = 1 - 2 y                   (2)
y'z' / (x'y' + x'z' + y'z') = -x + y + z = 1 - 2 x
```

Multiplying 2 of those and dividing by the third

```
x'^2 / (x'y' + x'z' + y'z') = (1 - 2 z) (1 - 2 y) / (1 - 2 x)
y'^2 / (x'y' + x'z' + y'z') = (1 - 2 z) (1 - 2 x) / (1 - 2 y)        (3)
z'^2 / (x'y' + x'z' + y'z') = (1 - 2 x) (1 - 2 y) / (1 - 2 z)
```

Therefore up to a constant factor

```
x' ~ sqrt[(1 - 2 z) (1 - 2 y) / (1 - 2 x)]
y' ~ sqrt[(1 - 2 z) (1 - 2 x) / (1 - 2 y)]                           (4)
z' ~ sqrt[(1 - 2 x) (1 - 2 y) / (1 - 2 z)]
```

Since we know that `x', y', z'` must sum to one this is enough to solve.

But: we needn't actually completely solve for `x', y', z'`. Since we are only interested in unequal pairs, all we need are the conditional probabilities `x'y' / (x'y' + x'z' + y'z')`, `x'z' / (x'y' + x'z' + y'z')` and `y'z' / (x'y' + x'z' + y'z')`. These we can compute using equation (2).

We then halve each of them to get the probabilities for ordered pairs and draw from the six legal pairs with these probabilities.

## Naive:

This is based on the (arbitrary in my opinion) postulate that after the first draw with probability `x', y', z'`, the second must have conditional probability `0, y' / (y'+z'), z' / (y'+z')` if first was `0` `x' / (x'+z'), 0, z' / (x'+z')` if first was `1` and probability `x' / (x'+y'), y' / (x'+y'), 0)` if first was `2`.

This has the disadvantage that as far as I can tell there is no simple, closed-form solution and the second and first draws are quite different.

The advantage is that one can use it directly with `np.random.choice`; this is, however, so slow that in the implementation below I give a workaround that avoids this function.

After some algebra one finds:

```
1/x' - x' = c (1 - 2x)
1/y' - y' = c (1 - 2y)
1/z' - z' = c (1 - 2z)
```

where `c = 1/x' + 1/y' + 1/z' - 1`. This I only managed to solve numerically.

## Implementation and results:

And here is the implementation.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize

def f_pairs(n, p):
    p = np.asanyarray(p)
    p /= p.sum()
    assert np.all(p <= 0.5)
    pp = 1 - 2*p

    # the following two lines show how to compute x', y', z'
    # pp = np.sqrt(pp.prod()) / pp
    # pp /= pp.sum()
    # now pp contains x', y', z'

    i, j = np.triu_indices(3, 1)
    i, j = i[::-1], j[::-1]
    pairs = np.c_[np.r_[i, j], np.r_[j, i]]
    pp6 = np.r_[pp/2, pp/2]
    return pairs[np.random.choice(6, size=(n,), replace=True, p=pp6)]

def f_opt(n, p):
    p = np.asanyarray(p)
    p /= p.sum()
    pp = 1 - 2*p
    def target(l):
        lp2 = l*pp/2
        return (np.sqrt(1 + lp2**2) - lp2).sum() - 1
    l = optimize.root(target, 8).x
    lp2 = l*pp/2
    pp = np.sqrt(1 + lp2**2) - lp2
    fst = np.random.choice(3, size=(n,), replace=True, p=pp)
    snd = (
        (np.random.random((n,)) < (1 / (1 + (pp[(fst+1)%3] / pp[(fst-1)%3]))))
        + fst + 1) % 3
    return np.c_[fst, snd]

def f_naive(n, p):
    p = np.asanyarray(p)
    p /= p.sum()
    pp = 1 - 2*p
    def target(l):
        lp2 = l*pp/2
        return (np.sqrt(1 + lp2**2) - lp2).sum() - 1
    l = optimize.root(target, 8).x
    lp2 = l*pp/2
    pp = np.sqrt(1 + lp2**2) - lp2
    return np.array([np.random.choice(3, (2,), replace=False, p=pp)
                    for _ in range(n)])

def check_sol(p, sol):
    N = len(sol)
    print("Frequencies [value: observed, desired]")
    c1 = np.bincount(sol[:, 0], minlength=3) / N
    print(f"1st column:  0: {c1[0]:8.6f} {p[0]:8.6f}  1: {c1[1]:8.6f} {p[1]:8.6f}  2: {c1[2]:8.6f} {p[2]:8.6f}")
    c2 = np.bincount(sol[:, 1], minlength=3) / N
    print(f"2nd column:  0: {c2[0]:8.6f} {p[0]:8.6f}  1: {c2[1]:8.6f} {p[1]:8.6f}  2: {c2[2]:8.6f} {p[2]:8.6f}")
    c = c1 + c2
    print(f"1st or 2nd:  0: {c[0]:8.6f} {2*p[0]:8.6f}  1: {c[1]:8.6f} {2*p[1]:8.6f}  2: {c[2]:8.6f} {2*p[2]:8.6f}")
    print()
    print("2nd column conditioned on 1st column [value 1st: val / prob 2nd]")
    for i in range(3):
        idx = np.flatnonzero(sol[:, 0]==i)
        c = np.bincount(sol[idx, 1], minlength=3) / len(idx)
        print(f"{i}: 0 / {c[0]:8.6f} 1 / {c[1]:8.6f} 2 / {c[2]:8.6f}")
    print()

# demo
p = 0.4, 0.35, 0.25
n = 1000000
print("Method: Naive")
check_sol(p, f_naive(n//10, p))
print("Method: naive, optimized")
check_sol(p, f_opt(n, p))
print("Method: Timeless")
check_sol(p, f_pairs(n, p))
```

Sample output:

```
Method: Naive
Frequencies [value: observed, desired]
1st column:  0: 0.449330 0.400000  1: 0.334180 0.350000  2: 0.216490 0.250000
2nd column:  0: 0.349050 0.400000  1: 0.366640 0.350000  2: 0.284310 0.250000
1st or 2nd:  0: 0.798380 0.800000  1: 0.700820 0.700000  2: 0.500800 0.500000

2nd column conditioned on 1st column [value 1st: val / prob 2nd]
0: 0 / 0.000000 1 / 0.608128 2 / 0.391872
1: 0 / 0.676133 1 / 0.000000 2 / 0.323867
2: 0 / 0.568617 1 / 0.431383 2 / 0.000000

Method: naive, optimized
Frequencies [value: observed, desired]
1st column:  0: 0.450606 0.400000  1: 0.334881 0.350000  2: 0.214513 0.250000
2nd column:  0: 0.349624 0.400000  1: 0.365469 0.350000  2: 0.284907 0.250000
1st or 2nd:  0: 0.800230 0.800000  1: 0.700350 0.700000  2: 0.499420 0.500000

2nd column conditioned on 1st column [value 1st: val / prob 2nd]
0: 0 / 0.000000 1 / 0.608132 2 / 0.391868
1: 0 / 0.676515 1 / 0.000000 2 / 0.323485
2: 0 / 0.573727 1 / 0.426273 2 / 0.000000

Method: Timeless
Frequencies [value: observed, desired]
1st column:  0: 0.400756 0.400000  1: 0.349099 0.350000  2: 0.250145 0.250000
2nd column:  0: 0.399128 0.400000  1: 0.351298 0.350000  2: 0.249574 0.250000
1st or 2nd:  0: 0.799884 0.800000  1: 0.700397 0.700000  2: 0.499719 0.500000

2nd column conditioned on 1st column [value 1st: val / prob 2nd]
0: 0 / 0.000000 1 / 0.625747 2 / 0.374253
1: 0 / 0.714723 1 / 0.000000 2 / 0.285277
2: 0 / 0.598129 1 / 0.401871 2 / 0.000000
```

Comment: Ouch.  Good programming.  Terrible descriptive statistics.   This is why you don't tune your analysis method to the expected probabilities (not your problem @PaulPanzer, the problem specification is bad)

Comment: Not sure why you're doing `assert np.all(p <= 0.5)` The question now includes `p` values of `.8` and `.7`.

Comment: @DanielF because I was not paying attention and thinking in terms of probabilities. Thanks for catching that one!

Comment: I'm not sure your starting point is correct.  You're not taking into account that the second draw's porbability is dependant on the first.  For probability without replacement I think the equation should be `x' + y' * x' / (1-y') + z' * x* / (1-z') = x` which doesn't simplify in any way I can find to your equation. In fact your method doesn't match the probabililities from the experimental data in the problem.

Comment: also `p.sum()` must always be `2` for the problem as stated, not `1`, the probabilities at each draw must sum to 1.

Comment: No, my problem is still with the fundemntal way you designate the probabilities neglecting the history of draws.  That's not sampling without replacement.  If you could prove it by calculating the the `x'y'z'` values and then actually doing a sampling without replacement (instead of the selection you've done) I'd be a bit less skeptical.